# Symfony 2.6 checked by default checkboxes

Tags: symfony, checkbox, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

How I can make checkboxes checked by default based on data from database?
Now my form looks like:

```
      ...
      ->add(
        "role", "entity", [
          "class"    => "AppDefaultBundle:OptionRole",
          "required" => false,
          "label"    => "Roles for user: ",
          "property" => "name",
          "expanded" => true,
          "multiple" => true
        ]
      )
      ...
```

And I want to select defaults for this checkboxes based on data from other table.

Comment: The only self contained method for accessing the entity from inside a form type that I know of is to use a listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably add the choices property: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices

In your case you should have an array with all OptionRoles relevant for the (User ?) entity you are working on (the one you create the form for).

Assuming the doctrine User model knows it's OptionRoles (most likely a ManyToMany association) the form should automatically check the checkboxes of the Users OptionRoles.

Here is one example:

```
[ 
    'label' => 'Select Modules',
    'class' => 'Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Module',
    'choices' => $this->availableModules(),
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true
]
```

...

```
public function availableModules()
{
    return $this->get('doctrine')
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Module')
    ->findAll();
}
```